# iOS available architecture issue

Tags: ios, armv7, armv6

I'm little bit confused about the architectures available in iOS build settings.

I found that there are 4 types:

1. `i386`
2. `armv6`
3. `armv7`
4. `armv7s`.

I know `i386` is for simulator, `armv6` is for iOS devices (older devices, think so).

But I'm confused about armv7 and armv7s.

1) What is the difference between armv7 and armv7s ?

2) Will the `armv7` and `armv7s` architecture based apps support older iOS version ?

I searched but couldn't get any useful information.
Please help me to understand the difference, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The i386, ARMv6, ARMv7 and ARMV7S are processor architectures (instruction sets), the ARMv7S is found in the iPad 4 and iPhone 5 (with the Apple A6 processor).

The Apple designed processor `A6` is the first one to be of the ARMv7S architecture. It's fully ARMv7 compatible, but has some specific optimalisation added by Apple. These optimalisation will not work in normal ARMv7 that is why they added the s.

Wikipedia calls it [Switft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_A6#cite_note-A6NamedSwift-3) and AnandTech has a nice post about:[The iPhone 5 review - Decoding Swift](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6330/the-iphone-5-review/5)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, armv6 supports up to the iPhone 3G, armv7 is for all iPads and the iPhone 3G S and up.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices

Comment: That's for the latest iPad 4/iPhone 5 A6X processor.